# What is the Authentication scope necessary to read comments in Google Sheets from Python

Tags: google-drive-api

I can't figure out what authentication scope I need to get comments from a file.  I ran this code:

```
SCOPES = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds',
         'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
"""Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
"""
creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            r'C:\Users\morton.hsiao\OneDrive - 247 Customer Pvt. Ltd\workspace\247\DriveApiCredentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# Call the Drive v3 API
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=1, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

This works fine.  Then I ran this:

```
x = service.comments().list(fileId='FILEID).execute()
items = x.get('files', [])
print(items)
```

and I got:
HttpError: https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/FILEID/comments?alt=json returned "Insufficient Permission: Request had insufficient authentication scopes.">

How do I get a list of scopes sufficient for things such as this?

Comment: At the method of "Comments: list" in Drive API v3`, these scopes of `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive`, `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly` can be used. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/comments/list) In your script, one of them is included. So although I'm not sure whether this is the direct solution, how about deleting `token.pickle` file and reauthorize the scopes?

Comment: When I did I reauthorized and got: Warning: Scope has changed from "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive" to "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive".  Then I ran it again and I still got the same error.  I think this is why it's so hard to be a software engineer at Google.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize that my comment was not useful for your situation. When I could find the issue and solution, I would like to tell you.

Comment: This moved me onto the next error: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"].  My newest error is the method needs the fields parameter.  Of course that's not in the documentation either

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Here are a few tips for Drive API v3.

[This documentation][1] is really demoralizing for a non-programmer, but I now know its wrong, I'm not an idiot for this reason.  Do not read it.  Here are two major mistakes.
 1. fileId is not a positional parameter like this documentation leads you to believe.  You have to specify it like VBA, with words before it.  They call that a named parameter
2. You need a fields parameter.  You specify it like fields = "*"

Here's a better [link][2].  It's not an easy link to find and its only for curl, not python.  If you go through the front door, this [link][3] leads to a 404 error. The scope that they tell you is wrong.  The scope that worked for me is:  ['googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', "googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "googleapis.com/auth/drive"].

Also one other subtle victory.  The get method for python is not documented.  My running theory is that you look at the response from the curl thingy and you put the name of the field into get.  So for comments, its "comments".  I've seen "items" in documentation elsewhere.  Ignore it.  I have to say, for people who's full time job is to bang their head against the wall reverse engineering a process the penetrate the CIA or NSA.  You have my respect.  This must be what it feels like.

So here is my full code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets', "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
"""Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
Prints the names and ids of the first 1 files the user has access to.
"""
creds = None
# The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
# created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
# time.
if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            'DriveApiCredentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

# Call the Drive v3 API
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=1, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
x = service.comments().list(fileId=secret code from above, fields='*').execute()
items = x.get('comments', [])
print(items)


  [1]: https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/python/latest/drive_v3.comments.html
  [2]: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/comments/list?apix_params=%7B%22fileId%22%3A%2212TBoX2UI_Yu2MA2ZN3p9f-cZsySE4et1slwpgjZbSzw%22%2C%22fields%22%3A%22*%22%7D
  [3]: https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-comments
```